# Wouldn't it be against the use of an optional object for validation?

Tags: java, spring, validation, option-type

I have a CRUD job.

Read -> Retrieves one object. Most have a value, but if an incorrect ID is entered, there may be no return value.

So we wrap it in an Optional object and return it.

Create -> Let's pass.

Update -> Update the object mentioned in Read.

Delete -> Deletes the object mentioned in Read.

Here, there is an ID that specifies the object to be updated or deleted (data row in DB).

The problem is I'm not sure if an object with this id exists in the DB or not.

I want to perform update or delete only when there is a value with ID in the DB.

The method I thought of at this time is to execute the first-mentioned Read method, receive an object wrapped in Optional, and pass if it is through orElseThrow().

If not, I used a method that raises a Throw exception.

But something seems wrong with this.

1. Optional returned after inquiry is destroyed after only checking whether there is a value or not.
2. But other than this, I can't think of a way to know if the DB really has a value.
3. Wouldn't it be better to write if == null instead?

Below is the code I implemented.

Please suggest a good way.

```
public Optional<CallCounselEntity> getCallCounselByUserId(UUID userId, UUID counselId) {
        return return callCounselRepository.findByUserId(userId, counselId);
    }



public CallCounselEntity updateCallCounsel(CallCounselEntity callCounsel) {
        **getCallCounselByUserId(callCounsel.getUserId(),callCounsel.getCounselId()).orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("No Search Data"));**
        callCounselRepository.save(callCounsel));

        return callCounsel;
}
```

Comment: Don’t waste you time by thinking whether an “optional is destroyed”, that’s not different to all the other billion objects that get “destroyed” without you ever thinking about them. Instead, think about the “Check-then-Act” antipattern and why it is a problem and whether `save` doesn’t already throw an exception when an ID doesn’t exist (or at least, should have an option to do so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by 'optional gets destroyed'?

You want `CallCounselEntity entity = getCallCounselByUserId(...).orElseThrow(...)`. If the code doesn't throw, then the method continues with `entity` now being assigned a non-optional value which you can use to make the update. If the code throws, then, well, any remaining code in your method referencing `entity` will never be reached. That's the whole point.

So, to sum up, the following is perfectly valid code for your scenario:

```
CallCounselEntity entity = getCallCounselByUserId(...).orElseThrow(...)
/* perform your update here */
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
getCallCounselByUserId(...).ifPresent(existingCounsel -> { 
    /* perform your update here */ 
})
```

or

```
getCallCounselByUserId(...).ifPresentOrElse(existingCounsel -> { 
    /* perform your update here */ 
}, () -> throw new RuntimeException(...))
```

if you still want to throw the exception for non-existent entities.

Comment: First of all, my explanation was a little lacking.

The update target data I want (CallCounselEntity ) has already been passed as a parameter from the controller.

So, the Optional(Entity) created through getCallCounselByUserId(..) is the target data before update, and it is used only to know if there is a value.
So, unless my code-based exception is raised, the data is there, and Optional(Entity) loses its value and is no longer used. (Destruction)

Comment: I also tried the second method, but the downside is that nothing happens in case of wrong ID input. (There is no way to signal something like an exception.)


The last method is unfortunately not supported as it uses Java8.

Comment: Here's why I didn't write CallCounselEntity entity = ... in the first.

This is because the data obtained through getCallCounselByUserId(..) does not need to be used anymore by checking whether it exists.

Comment: If you want to check whether or not a given entity exists, without loading the state of that entity, why not just use `repository.existsById()`?

Comment: Also note that, depending on the use case, it might not be a good idea to allow clients of `updateCallCounsel` to just overwrite the entire entity data with arbitrary values. If you ever want to restrict the set of properties that can be updated this way, a better pattern would be to load the entity, then apply the allowed changes by copying them from one object to the other

Comment: I heard the example in JPA, but for my circumstances, the Entity has no original meaning. The actual query is implemented directly as @Query("select * ...").

As a result, I had to write a new select exists query, so I tried to apply an existing query.

Comment: And I will study the pattern you mentioned later.

Perhaps a clear solution to my situation seems hard to come by right now. Thank you for your help.